# Scrollable ListView with customized BaseAdapter is very slow

Tags: android, listview, android-view

I have a customized BaseAdapter for my listView with this code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
  if (convertView == null) 
  { 
  } 
  else 
  {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }
  convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_submissions_customisation, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.JournalName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.JournalName);
   holder.SubmissionTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SubmissionTitle);
   holder.SubmissionDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SubmissionDate);
   holder.statusOk=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusOkImage);
   holder.statusRejected=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusRejectedImage);
   holder.statusProcessing=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusProcessingImage);
   convertView.setTag(holder);

  ImageView statusOk=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusOkImage);
  ImageView statusRejected=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusRejectedImage);
  ImageView statusProcessing=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusProcessingImage);

  MDPIActivity mdpi = new MDPIActivity();
  Context context =mdpi.getContext();
  LocalDatabase localDatabase = new LocalDatabase(context); //Instantiation of the DB
  int status = localDatabase.getSubmissionStatus(position+1);

  if (status==102 | status==19)
  {
      statusRejected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
  else
  {
      if (status==29)
      {
      statusOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
      else
      {
          statusProcessing.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
  }

  holder.JournalName.setText(submissionsArrayList.get(position).getJournalTitle()+"-"+submissionsArrayList.get(position).getID());
  holder.SubmissionTitle.setText(submissionsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
  holder.SubmissionDate.setText(submissionsArrayList.get(position).getDate());

  return convertView;
}

 static class ViewHolder {
  TextView JournalName;
  TextView SubmissionTitle;
  TextView SubmissionDate;
  ImageView statusOk;
  ImageView statusRejected;
  ImageView statusProcessing;
 }
```

All works wel but the creation of the list on the display and the scrolling is pretty slow.
I used this for éy list too:

```
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
android:scrollingCache="true"
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
```

But the view changing from the previeous view to the listview is slow and the scrolling of the list too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All apart first do this thing
Move this code in the if condition when "convert view is null"
 `convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_submissions_customisation, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.JournalName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.JournalName);
   holder.SubmissionTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SubmissionTitle);
   holder.SubmissionDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SubmissionDate);
   holder.statusOk=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusOkImage);
   holder.statusRejected=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusRejectedImage);
   holder.statusProcessing=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusProcessingImage);
   convertView.setTag(holder);`
You are not using the adapter efficiently by coding as you did.
The above way will improve the performance for sure.
In nutshell, you must inflate the view for list row only when the convert view is null. 
Also, different views in the row's view must be initialized with the convertView itself.
Then you set holder view as the tag to the convert view and the adapter will continuously provide the same view instead of inflating the new one every time.
**Edit:**You should move the code for getting the context and instantiating the db from the getView() method.
Just make a class level variable "mContext" in your adapter class and instantiate it in the constructor of your adapter by passing activity's context.
Then at same place (constructor) instantiate the db also.

Comment: Thank you akkilis, the problem now is that the elements position is changing when I am scrooling and i use this information in my if condition for some images.

Comment: its no changing actually but seems to be changed.

Comment: this is because, if for any element of a row you have not set data and that element was present in the previous row with some data, it will be displayed same because now you are reusing the convert view.

Comment: I don't understand you akkilis, sorry. What i have to do for conserving my element position?

Comment: I have made this but how to use the LocalDatabase object in he getview method when this object is instanciated in the Adapter consructor?

Comment: just make it the class level variable to the adapter class. So by this way you are instantiating it only once

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7835/discussion-between-akkilis-and-ana)

Comment: Ok, I have made this, but the code your mentioned before, i have still to put him in the f condition when "convert view is null" ? Because, when I am doing this, I have still the same problem with the position

Comment: please click on the link of chat in my above comment and add your further comments there for easy communication

Answer (score 0):

Why you **always** inflate a convertView? If view not null you should change view as you want and no inflate a view again. Use code like this on the top of *getView*

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_submissions_customisation, null);
} else {
    //convertView  is already inflated. No inflate it again!
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.JournalName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.JournalName);
```

Comment: whats the need to do "holder = new ViewHolder();" when you are already getting it as the tag of the convert view?? In my view, doing this is of no use.

Comment: The same problem as for akkilis,  the elements position is changing when I am scrooling and i use this information in my if condition for some images.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) 
      { 
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_submissions_customisation, null);
         holder = new ViewHolder();
         holder.JournalName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.JournalName);
         holder.SubmissionTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SubmissionTitle);
         holder.SubmissionDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SubmissionDate);
         holder.statusOk=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusOkImage);
         holder.statusRejected=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusRejectedImage);
         holder.statusProcessing=ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusProcessingImage);
         convertView.setTag(holder);
      } 
      else 
      {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }

   ...
}
```

This way,your initialization of holder's object would just be for first element of your list.then it will always be in else grabbing previous settings.

Comment: Thank you, this is working but i have a element position problem which i resolved with the help of Akkilis.