# Custom listview scrollin isn't smooth

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I've created a custom listview which is working great apart from the fact that the list doesn't smooth scroll. Its choppy and slow.

Here's the code where I populate the listview:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        }

        FilmRecord film = films.get(position);
        if (film != null) {
            TextView filmTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filmtitle);
            TextView filmShowingDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filmshowingtime);
            TextView filmAdded = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filmadded);
            TextView filmLocations = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filmlocations);
            TextView filmDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filmdescription);
            TextView filmProvider = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filmprovider);
            TextView filmTicketUrl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.filmticketurl);


            if (filmTitle != null) {
                filmTitle.setText(film.filmTitle);
            }

            if(filmDescription != null) {
                filmDescription.setText(film.filmDescription );
            }

            if(filmLocations != null) {
                filmLocations.setText(film.filmLocations );
            }

            if(filmShowingDate != null) {
                filmShowingDate.setText("Showing: " + film.filmShowingDate );
            }

            if(filmAdded != null) {
                filmAdded.setText("Added on: " + film.filmAdded );
            }

            if(filmProvider != null) {
                filmProvider.setText(film.filmProvider );
            }

            if(filmTicketUrl != null) {
                filmTicketUrl.setText(film.filmTicketUrl );
            }
        }

        //Check who the provider is and set the imageview to provider logo
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.providerImage);
        if(film.filmProvider.equals("Cineworld")) {
            Log.d("Provider", "Provider is Cineworld");
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cineworld);
        }
        else if(film.filmProvider.equals("Show Film Fist")){
            Log.d("Provider", "Provider is Show Film Fist");
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.show_film_first);
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Has anyone had similar issues when creating a custom listview? Any help as always would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You need to change your logic. You are checking each fields for null, I think it will not give any error, when you will set text without checking null. And there must be two if for Showing: and  Added on:. but you can remove these two if also by setting those two pre_text in your POJO. Hope it will clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `ViewHolder` approach.

because finding the View by id also takes time to execute.

by using `ViewHolder` approach you will be able to minimize the load created during finding View by id by caching the views :)

[Here](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/) is nice tutorial how to do that.

### Edit:

**What ViewHolder approach do is:**

Say you have 4 visible items in your `ListView` at a time. You have to inflate the `View` 4 time and `findViewById()` 4 times only even if you scroll to 1000th item in `ListView`.

But if you don't use `ViewHolder` and you have put

```
if (v == null) {
   LayoutInflater vi = ...;
}else{
   //... other implementation 
}
```

You have to inflate the `View` 4 time only, but `findViewById()` will be called **every time** when the `getView()` is called (usually when `ListView` is scrolled).

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks again fo the tutorial. I've implemented the code accordingly. As soon as I scoll down the list, I get repeated list items. E.g. row 5 and 6 have the same content as row 0. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Hi Adil, thanks for replying :) I've be tweaking the code and it doesn't repeat list items. But now I'm back to the situation where I doesn't scroll smooth lol getView() code is at [Pastie](http://pastie.org/3427339)

Comment: the updated code worked. Many thanks for helping me out :) and thanks for the pastie.org link. Handy site for comments.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today and while using the viewHolder pattern the scrolling was still laggy, until I wanted to show the problem to a colleague and noticed that scrolling was smooth. 
So the problem in my case was that I was connected to the debugger and that slowed things down.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in `films.get(position)`?

If you are reading from a database then your scrolling might really be bad here...

When using a database you should load the data into the adapter during onCreate, probably something like that (but with your previous listview layout etc.)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    List<FilmRecord> values = films.getAllFilms();


    ArrayAdapter<FilmRecord> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<FilmRecord>(this,
                your_list_item_layout_id, values);
    your_list_view.setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In the `getView()` method you just have to ask the adapter:

```
FilmRecord film = getItem(position);
```

Comment: Yeah i'm reading from a database. How should I go about avoiding this issue then?

Comment: Hi ramdroid. I've modified the code as suggested with the addition of @Adil's suggestion which uses ViewHolder. Both of which have been excellent improvements on the code. But with these changes I have another issue. As soon as I scoll down the list, I get repeated list items. E.g. row 5 and 6 have the same content as row 0. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this question and see my answer there.It shows how you should declare your components in your custom adapter class.Making these changes to your class will definitely solve your problem as the question i suggested here also had the similar issue as yours:[Scrolable ListView with costumized BaseAdapter is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324181/scrolable-listview-with-costumized-baseadapter-is-very-slow/9325417#9325417)

Answer (score 0):

check this link 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/android-smooth-list-scrolling.html

and also add this in Activity OnCreate() method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //StrictMode for smooth list scroll
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*----- 
        ListView 
        Custom Adapter set data....
    ------*/
```

}