# List scrolling lag

Tags: android, listactivity, smooth-scrolling

My app is a **list activity** which contain 26 rows , each include image and text , every thing run fine but scrolling of list show some lag , its not smooth espically when scroll it fast as smooth as in default android contacts list ,

i tried : `lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);`

also tried to reduce the image size in each row till i replaced all images with ic_launcher images for test , but the same lag is there .

but it make no difference in smoothing the scroll of my list , any advice or help will be highly appreciated .
**note:**  classes named in arabic language.

**my code :**

**Menu Class:**

```
 public class Menu extends ListActivity {
   String classes[] = { "المقدمة", "رحلتي", "اليوم الأول",  "اليوم الثاني", "اليوم الثالث", 
         "اليوم الرابع", "اليوم الخامس", "اليوم السادس", "اليوم السابع", "اليوم الثامن", "اليوم التاسع", "اليوم العاشر", "اليوم الحادي عشر", 
         "اليوم الثاني عشر", "اليوم الثالث عشر", "اليوم الرابع عشر", "اليوم الخامس عشر", "اليوم السادس عشر", "اليوم السابع عشر", 
         "اليوم الثامن عشر", "اليوم التاسع عشر", "اليوم العشرون", "اليوم الحادي والعشرين", "اليوم الثاني والعشرين", "اليوم الثالث والعشرين", "الخاتمة"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // create background for whole list as image 
    ListView lv = getListView(); 
    lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);   
    lv.setCacheColorHint(0);  
    lv.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0xFFDAB999));
    lv.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent); 
    lv.setDividerHeight(10);
    lv.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0);
    lv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);

    setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this, classes));  }

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    if(cheese.equals("المقدمة")) cheese = "Introduction"; 
    if(cheese.equals("رحلتي")) cheese = "MyTrip"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الأول")) cheese = "Day1"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الثاني")) cheese = "Day2"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الثالث")) cheese = "Day3";
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الرابع")) cheese = "Day4"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الخامس")) cheese = "Day5"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم السادس")) cheese = "Day6";
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم السابع")) cheese = "Day7"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الثامن")) cheese = "Day8"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم التاسع")) cheese = "Day9";
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم العاشر")) cheese = "Day10"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الحادي عشر")) cheese = "Day11"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الثاني عشر")) cheese = "Day12";
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الثالث عشر")) cheese = "Day13"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الرابع عشر")) cheese = "Day14"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الخامس عشر")) cheese = "Day15";
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم السادس عشر")) cheese = "Day16"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم السابع عشر")) cheese = "Day17"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الثامن عشر")) cheese = "Day18";
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم التاسع عشر")) cheese = "Day19"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم العشرون")) cheese = "Day20"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الحادي والعشرين")) cheese = "Day21";
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الثاني والعشرين")) cheese = "Day22"; 
    if(cheese.equals("اليوم الثالث والعشرين")) cheese = "Day23"; 
    if(cheese.equals("الخاتمة")) cheese = "Conclusion"; 

    try{
        Intent ourIntent;
       if(position>1 &&  position<25) {
               Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.tsn.dr.MyDay");
               ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
               ourIntent.putExtra("cheese", cheese);}
       else {
               Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.tsn.dr." + cheese);
               ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);  }            
          startActivity(ourIntent);  }                                                                                                 
                 catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                          e.printStackTrace();  }}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);

getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
AttributeSet attrs) {

if (name .equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
try {

LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);

new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {


view .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border3);

((TextView) view).setTextSize(25); 


Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf");     
((TextView) view).setTypeface(face);
((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
});
return view;
} catch (InflateException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
}
return null;
}
});
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.aboutUs:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.tsn.dr.ABOUT");
        startActivity(i);

    break;
    case R.id.preferences:
        Intent p = new Intent("com.tsn.dr.PREFS");
        startActivity(p);
    break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
    break;
}
return false;
                }
         }
```

**MyArrayAdapter Class:**

```
 public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final String[] classes;
Typeface tf;

public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, String[] classes) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, classes);
    this.context = context;
    this.classes = classes;
              }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf"); 
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, true);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
    String s = classes[position];
    textView.setText(s);
    ((TextView)textView).setTypeface(tf); 


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الأول")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الثاني")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الثالث")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الرابع")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الخامس")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم السادس")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم السابع")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الثامن")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم التاسع")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم العاشر")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الحادي عشر")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الثاني عشر")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الثالث عشر")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الرابع عشر")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الخامس عشر")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم السادس عشر")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم السابع عشر")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الثامن عشر")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم التاسع عشر")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم العشرون")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الحادي والعشرين")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الثاني والعشرين")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الثالث والعشرين")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("الخاتمة")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("رحلتي")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }


if ( s.startsWith("المقدمة")) {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }

return rowView;  }}
```

Comment: You are creating new row View every time when you scroll, you need to re-use the layouts, [use ViewHolder approach.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9359237/593709)

Comment: @Adil Soomro acually my friend i created my list by using classes and im not using listview XML , is that works with ViewHolder approach , thanks

Comment: all that matters is your Adapter's implementations.

Comment: try to disable scrollingCache of listview.

Comment: lv.setScrollingCache(False); 
i dont have a android dev setup now, so please sorry me if there is something wrong in the syntax.

Comment: its actually 
     lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

Comment: @sree i try it , the same , nothing changed

Comment: try to use switch case instead of if loop in getView(). It will have 26 if checks for each raw. so better use switch case and break the loop if matches.

Comment: @ i will check it and reply you . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf");` line from your `getView` method and use it as a field (Which makes it reusable). You can create your `TypeFace`  in `onCreate()` method for example.

And second, you are not recycling views. You are creating new row when your adapter calls `getView()` method. The proper implementation of `getView()` method is something like below:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
       // Inflate your row layout
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_XML_LAYOUT, null);
        // set your holder views here. For example;
        // holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        //
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Customize your row items here! For example:
    // if ( s.startsWith("اليوم الثاني والعشرين")) {
    // imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }

    return convertView;
}
```

For more efficiency, don't use time consuming operations in `getView()` method because it will be called everytime you fling/scroll on your listview.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i will try it my dear , im outside now , later and replay you ,thanks alot

Comment: thanks , but one more thing , if i increase the size of image in each row , this will lead to lag of scrolling again , how to solve that.